# Replacing Controller For Clicking Drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I have a Hitachi 5400 RPM 60.0 GB 2.5 hard drive that clicks once when it is powered on and is not recognizable in my computer or in disk management.  I have also tried connecting to a Linux box and used `fdisk -l` but no such luck the drive is not recognized.

To replace the controller to see if this will allow me to recover data from the drive, must I use the EXACT same make/model of what this drive is or will the controller from any 2.5 hard drive accomplish the same goal?

If not what other method is recommended to recover data from a hard drive that a PC does not recognize?

**EDIT**
The link to the possible duplicate ? gives options of how to recover data from a drive that your computer can still recognize.  My computer will not recognize the drive at all.

Comment: You will need to use the EXACT make and model. After you have recovered the data I would strongly recommend that you retire the drive.

Comment: @Burgi - yes, that is the plan!  There is data on the drive that I MUST recover.  Is it a guarantee that swapping the controller will allow me to recover the data or is it a 50/50?

Comment: Right now it's Schrödinger's cat. The drive is either dead or not. If it's a head crash, then keeping trying to spin it up with another controller is going to reduce your chances of success.

Comment: To low to upvote, but love the Schrödinger's cat reference!

Comment: Swapping the controller worked in less than 10% of the times I've tried it over the years.  If your drive has inbuilt full disk encryption, then you're basically SOL, even with a matching controller. If you REALLY need the data, contact a data recovery specialist for a free evaluation.

Comment: @TECHIE007 - I do not believe it has the inbuilt full disk encryption.  If this method works in less than 10%, is there a better method that you would recommend?

Comment: @TECHIE007 - that seems to be how to recover data when your PC can access the drive.  Since mine is not able to...  I have already tried UltimateBootCD as well as EaseUS Data Recovery and niether of them could recognize the drive.

Comment: @Burgi - Backups were destroyed by house fire - computer was with me.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that.